# how to use controller code in template .phtml file

Tags: magento-1.9

after visit this url : **sitename.com/example/module/createSimpleProduc**t , 
we are displaying link : **"create products"** ,  once we click on link, it will create new products in Database.

app/code/local/module/Example/controllers - Modulecontroller.php

```
class Module_Example_ModuleController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
        {
            echo 'This is index controller.   
                <br/>
                <a href="/example/module/createSimpleProduct">Create Simple Product</a>';

        }

    public function createSimpleProductAction()
        {
            $product = $this->_createProduct(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE);
            echo 'See <a href="/catalog/product/view/id/' . $product->getId() . '">create products</a>';
        }
```

we want to display this link & achieve same feature in product view page, so we added below code & gave **href link** to the button in **addtocart.phtml** file , but its giving fatal error :

```
 <button type="button" >
    <span>
    <?php echo 'See <a href="/catalog/product/view/id/' . $product->getId() . '">created simple product</a>' ?>
    </span>
    </button>
```

[image]

**Edit**

```
protected function _createProduct($type, $doSave=true) 
    {

        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

        // set madatory system attributes
        $rand = rand(1, 9999);
        $product
            ->setTypeId($type)     // e.g. Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE
            ->setAttributeSetId(17) // default attribute set
            ->setSku('CDSB_sku' . $rand) // generate some random SKU 
            ->setWebsiteIDs(array(1))
        ;           

        // make the product visible
        $product
            ->setCategoryIds(array(2,3))
            ->setStatus(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
            ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH) // visible in catalog and search
        ;
        // configure stock
        $product->setStockData(array(
            'use_config_manage_stock' => 1, // use global config ?
            'manage_stock'            => 0, // shoudl we manage stock or not?
            'is_in_stock'             => 1, 
            'qty'                     => 50,
        ));     

        // optimize performance, tell Magento to not update indexes
        $product
            ->setIsMassupdate(true)
            ->setExcludeUrlRewrite(true)
        ;

        // finally set custom data
        $product
            ->setName('Test Product #' . $rand) // add string attribute
            ->setShortDescription('Description') // add text attribute

            // set up prices
            ->setPrice(599)
            //->setSpecialPrice(19.99)
            ->setTaxClassId(2)    // Taxable Goods by default
            ->setWeight(1)
        ;

        // add product images
        $images = array(
            'thumbnail'   => 'image.png',
            'small_image' => 'image.png',
            'image'       => 'image.png',
        );

        $dir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'example/amasty/';

        foreach ($images as $imageType => $imageFileName) {
            $path = $dir . $imageFileName;
            if (file_exists($path)) {
                try {
                    $product->addImageToMediaGallery($path, $imageType, false);
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    echo $e->getMessage();
                }
            } else {
                echo "Can not find image by path: `{$path}`<br/>";
            }
        }

        if ($doSave)
            $product->save();

        return $product;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the `_createProduct` method? From what i can see you are trying to call `getId()` on something that is not an object. Also does `addtocart.phtml` have access to `$product` Also if you could show the whole error you are getting too, so we can see which file it is complaining about :)

Comment: @DanCarlyon please check `edit` part in question

Comment: addtocart.phtml code : http://pastebin.com/7C12E2x4

Comment: fatal error on line : `<span><span><?php echo 'See <a href="/catalog/product/view/id/' . $product->getId() . '">created simple product</a>' ?>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to create a new controller action and then call it when you click on "Create custom product" button in your `phtml`

```
public function createSimpleProductAndRedirectAction()
{
    if($product = $this->_createProduct(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE)){
        $this->_redirect("catalog/product/view/id/".$product->getId());
    }
}
```

Now use this action in your button `href`

```
<button type="button" > 
    <span> 
        <a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl("example/amasty/createSimpleProductAndRedirect"); ?>">created simple product</a>
    </span> 
</button>
```

Comment: The true isn't needed, if it isn't set then it would default to true. `protected function _createProduct($type, $doSave=true)`

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55118/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-and-dancarlyon

Answer (score 1):

In the addtocart.phtml you posted, the product is saved to `$_product` rather than `$product`

`<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>`

You should be able to do

```
<?php echo 'See <a href="/catalog/product/view/id/' . $_product->getId() . '">created simple product</a>' ?>
```

Comment: Thanks , i added like this in addtocart.phtml, still same issue : `<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $_product->getId(); ?>`

Comment: The `$this->getProduct()` is already there at the top of your template. Is it still the same error message?

Comment: no fatal error now, after i followed your updated answer but product is not creating in DB after clciking link......

Comment: Anything in system/exception logs ?

Comment: strange, there is no errors in log, once we click on link, its redirecting to proper url, but not creating products.....

Comment: when we click on [link1](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/example/amasty/createSimpleProduct) its ceating product. but when we click on [link in product view page](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html) , its not creating product.....

Comment: please click on link `CREATED SIMPLE PRODUCT`  below `Add to cart` in [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html)

Comment: When you say it's not creating the product how do you mean? If i click that link and it _creates the product_ then refresh the page i am on it still has all the data so the product must exist unless it is hard coded information i'm seeing. For example: http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/catalog/product/view/id/195098

Comment: i am checking under `catalog > Manage products` after clicking links.....

Comment: also in the module `app` code , we didt mentioned any template url, is that cause the issue ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55118/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-and-dancarlyon).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support, i got solution [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55118/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-and-dancarlyon).....